# How to make navigation bar change color when you scroll down the page?

Tags: jquery, nav

I would like the navigation bar to be transparent but when you scroll down the page it changes to color red for example.

```
<div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="logo">
       <a href="#"><img src="RepublicSquare_logo.svg" style="height: 80px;"></a>
       </div>
        <div class="navMain">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qrhjdfmd/

```
var a = $(".nav").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > a)
    {   
       $('.nav').css({"background":"red"});
    } else {
       $('.nav').css({"background":"transparent"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know how to make it fade to color not just appear?

Comment: Add CSS transition property like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qrhjdfmd/ . Please, mark my answer as correct if it's useful.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. I used this - .nav {transition-duration: 1s;} along with this Jquery: $(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('.nav');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(34,34,34,0.9)');
       } else {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });
});

Comment: Sorry I can't vote up your answer, it says I don't have a reputation of 15. But I do greatly appreciate your time and assistance.

Comment: Sorry, I posted jsfiddle link but I forgot to save the changes. Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/qrhjdfmd/1/

Answer (score 3):

If anyone would be looking for a non-jquery solution (vanilla js), here it is:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var scrollStart = 0;
    var nav = document.querySelector(".nav");
    var offset = navbarElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    document.onscroll = function (e) {
        scrollStart = e.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
        if (scrollStart > offset.top) {
            nav.style.background-color, rgba(34,34,34,0.9);
        } else {
            nav.style.background-color = "transparent";
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*Solution by OP.*

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('.nav');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(34,34,34,0.9)');
       } else {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });
});
```

***CSS***

```
.nav {
transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

This should make your navigation transparent and when you scroll it will change to rgba(34,34,34,0.9)