# Jquery - Navbar color change on scroll won't reverse

Tags: jquery, css

Working on a for fun site trying to get my navbar to change from transparent to color after user scrolls past banner title. I used the second solution on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308425/how-to-make-navigation-bar-change-color-when-you-scroll-down-the-page-solved). Problem is, my navbar color doesn't change back when I scroll back up.

Here is a pared down [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8jjw0g5/) that demonstrates the problem. What is the key difference between the solution above and my version that is causing the discrepency?

Here is the code from the fiddle:

`html`:

```
<header class="site-header">

 <nav class="site-nav">

  <div class="trigger">
      <a class="page-link" href="#"><span>About Me</span></a>
  </div>
</nav>

<a class="site-title" href="#/">My Site</a>

</header>
<article>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus diam sit amet orci ullamcorper facilisis volutpat sed ante. Suspendisse ut blandit justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer volutpat nunc eget fermentum dictum. Phasellus tempus et diam a consequat. Donec vitae enim nunc. Phasellus pretium suscipit turpis, a mollis metus feugiat ac. Vivamus lacus ante, cursus id porttitor et, imperdiet id nibh. Nunc tristique elementum mi a tempus. Ut placerat ac sapien nec rhoncus. Cras interdum orci erat, placerat tincidunt quam finibus a. Suspendisse aliquam non risus congue vulputate. Aenean congue justo sed tincidunt laoreet. Nam augue sapien, commodo vel lacus in, suscipit venenatis eros.
</p>
</article>
```

`css`:

```
.site-header{
 height:400px;
}

.site-nav{
 line-height: 56px;
width: 100%;
text-align:right;
position:fixed;

transition-duration: .5s;
}

.site-title {
position:absolute;
top:40%;
left:30%;

font-family: serif;
font-size: 72px;
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 56px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
margin-bottom: 0;
float: left;

color: black;

}
```

`js`:

```
/*Background color change on scroll past title*/
var changePoint = $(".site-title").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
if($(this).scrollTop() > changePoint){
    $('.site-nav').css({'background-color': '#DDD'});
} else{
    $('.site-nav').css({'background-color': 'transparant'});
}
});
```

Comment: use `transparent` , not `transparant` on `background-color`

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if your code is perfectly fine! The one problem is that you have a typo in your second CSS declaration.

Instead of: `$('.site-nav').css({'background-color': 'transparant'});`, you should be saying: `$('.site-nav').css({'background-color': 'transparent'});`

I tried changing the letters on your fiddle and it seems to work on my safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

see here : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqqhreh8/1/)**

use `transparent` , not `transparant` on `background-color`

JQ

```
var changePoint = $(".site-title").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > changePoint){
        $('.site-nav').css({'background-color': '#DDD'});
    } else{
        $('.site-nav').css({'background-color': 'transparent'});
    }
});
```